# How to access s3 bucket with key and secret?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been given some credentials to access a S3 bucket. I have what looks like a username, password, key and secret.

I've logged into my S3 account but where do I plug in the details?

Comment: If you login to the AWS Management Console (using the username and password) and go to the S3 console, is the bucket visible? Are you looking for programmatic access to the bucket, or are you happy accessing it via a web browser? Please tell us more about what you are wanting to do with the bucket.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Accessing using browser is fine thx. I was not able to log in using the username/password provided

Comment: A username + password is only used to login to the web-based AWS management console. The Access Key + Secret Key is used for the AWS CLI (you can store it by using the `aws configure` command). When you say "I was not able to log in", what were you trying to login to?

Answer (score 2):

You can use them as

**AWS Web Console**: username and password

- [How IAM users sign in to AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_sign-in.html)

**AWSCLI**: key and secret (for programmatic access)

- [Configuration basics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html)
- [Named profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html)
- [Environment variables to configure the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html)

Once you will setup/configure your key/secret then you can access it from awscli, boto3 or any SDK of your choice.
For example,

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket
aws s3 ls
aws s3api list-objects --bucket text-content --query 'Contents[].{Key: Key, Size: Size}'
aws s3api list-buckets --query "Buckets[].Name"
```

---

**For complete set of commands of aws-cli you can follow:**

1. [s3api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/index.html)
2. [Leveraging the s3 and s3api Commands](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/leveraging-the-s3-and-s3api-commands/)
3. [aws s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/)